# Is there short way to exclude layout page from ResponseCache

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0

I want to cache page but the problem is that the button connect is
 also cached because it's in the layout. Is there a way to exclude layout page from cache and `.net core` will generate only the layout again and the inner page from cache without cachetag

```
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Default")]
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Response caching is literally caching the response, i.e. the entire HTML document. There is no concept of what is layout, a partial, etc. It's just an HTML document. You can use the `cache`/`distributed-cache` tag helper to cache portions of the view, but you cannot cache the entire response, if you only want to cache some portion (i.e. exclude the layout itself).

That said, you can certainly vary the cache on a particular header, whether a user is logged in or not, etc. So, depending on why you're wanting to not cache the layout, it might be possible to actually cache the whole response, including layout, and yet still present different versions.